# Improved support for displaying accidentals

Tags: feature-request

In 
[this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/87/purpose-of-double-sharps-and-double-flats/88#88), people use various ways to notate double sharps:

F##

Fx

F double-sharp

All of these are reasonable ways to work around the lack of an available double sharp symbol.  The same applies to the other accidentals- naturals, flats, etc...

Bret Pimentel has created a jQuery plugin that "attempts to identify accidentals (flats, naturals, sharps, double-flats, and double-sharps) typed in plain text, and convert them to the correct symbols."  It's explained and available at his [website](http://accidentals.bretpimentel.com/) and the source code is on github.

Could we look into integrating this plugin with this site?  Bret might even be interested in helping.

[image: Example output]

Comment: Related: http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/q/564/1678 and http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/q/2/1678. Yes, I agree there should be some system to easier represent musical symbols.

Comment: I think this is also an answer to [this feature request](http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/q/264/249). Can you post this there as an answer? You can form it as an answer, and link it to your question here, as this is still a valid feature request to implement this particular plugin.